# What is the difference between pseudorumination and coprophily?

Tags: digestion

Can someone please explain me difference between these two terms. any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Ruminants* (e.g. cows) is a classification of animals based on its digestive tract, so these are the animals having four-chambered stomacks. [*Pseudoruminant*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoruminant) (e.g. hippopotamus) have three-chambered stomacks in comparison with ruminants. *[Coprophilous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprophilous_fungi)* usually applied for different types of fungi that grow on animal dung.